# error:Interface type cannot be statically allocated ? map link

Tags: ios4, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator, iphone

I have variable is: `stateName = [store objectAtIndex:0];`

and Country: `country = [store objectAtIndex:1];`

and I put code like this:

```
NSString* urlString = @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@+
%@&daddr=Birmingham+UK",statName,country;
```

I tried to put code like this:

```
NSString *test = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", stateName];
```

> NSString *urlString =
>   @"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK",test;

It didn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you paste your code correctly and carefully? There's some syntax errors with what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use stringWithFormat if you're including object data in your string. So:

```
NSString* urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@+%@&daddr=Birmingham+UK",stateName,country];
```

and

```
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=%@+UK&daddr=Birmingham+UK",test];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to use current location? in upper textbox. lowwer textbox i have already.